# Google-cloud-speech "detecting language spoken automatically" feature detecting only one language

Tags: speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to use the paid version of google-cloud-speech speech-to-text feature with "Detecting language spoken automatically" feature. The problem is if I give 2 alternate languages (in my case "en-IN", "hi-IN"), then it is detecting whole speech as Hindi only though I have spoken initial 20 sec in Hindi and next in English. I don't think this is the expected behavior so please help me out resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an expected behavior, it detects a language and uses it, it can not switch. There are different providers which can decode mixed language, not google.

Comment: Can you let me know about those different providers? It would be of great help.

Comment: And are there any libraries with with I can detect the text (written in english only but vocabulary used is of multiple languages) in multiple languages?

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Is there any documentation showing that this is the expected behavior? [Their article about multiple language support](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multiple-languages) doesn't seem to clearly describe this as what is to be expected.